# Add up content of array to another array in php

Tags: php, arrays, push, addition

I want to have an array that contains a list of something, then I have another array that contains a list of something. I want to add those arrays up to each other. 
For example, I have this

```
<?php
$greetings1 = array (
      'a' => 'hello',
      'b' => 'hi'
      );
$greetings2 = array ('c' => 'hey',
      'd' => 'greetings'
     );
array_push($greetings1, $greetings2);

foreach($greetings1 as $a => $b) {
 echo $a.' and '.$b."<br/>";
}
?>
```

I want it so that the output is:

> a and hello 
>   b and hi 
>   c and hey 
>   d and greetings

the real output of the php code above is:

> a and hello 
>   b and hi 
>   0 and Array

So how do I properly add the two arrays up? 

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can array_merge

```
<?php
$greetings1 = array(
    'a' => 'hello',
    'b' => 'hi',
);
$greetings2 = array(
    'c' => 'hey',
    'd' => 'greetings',
);

$greetings = array_merge($greetings1, $greetings2);
```

Which will output:

```
Array
(
    [a] => hello
    [b] => hi
    [c] => hey
    [d] => greetings
)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
array_merge($greetings1, $greetings2);
```

array_push just adds an element at the end of the array (in that case another array).

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [array_merge](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)